# Groovy Regular matching everything between a tag

Tags: regex, groovy

I have a text string something like this:

```
def ctext = """This is the normal text.
This is the again normal text.
<code>int main(){
printf('Hello World!\n');
return 0;}
</code>

This is the again normal text.
This is the again normal text.

<code>
public static void main (String args[]){
System.out.println('Hello World!\n');
return 0;}
</code>

The last line ....
"""
```

I want to replace all the occurrence of the the text between the `'<code>(.*)</code>'` section by passing this to a method like `doBeautify(codeText)`.

I am trying like this, but no luck:

```
def matches = ctext =~ /<code>(.*)<\/code>/
```

Any help appriciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, the `.` does not match `\r` and `\n`. Try:

```
def matches = ctext =~ /(?s)<code>(.*?)<\/code>/
```

where `(?s)` is called the DOT-ALL modifier (making the `.` match anything). I also made the `.*` non-greedy by placing a `?` after it. Otherwise, it'd match the very first `<code>` and the very last `</code>` (and everything in between).

Realize that your regex breaks if your input look like:

```
<code>int main(){
printf('Hello </code> World!\n');
</code>
```

to name just one of many corner cases. In that case, you need a proper parser for you language.

### EDIT

A little demo:

```
def ctext = """This is the normal text.
This is the again normal text.
<code>int main(){
printf('Hello World!\\n');
return 0;}
</code>

This is the again normal text.
This is the again normal text.

<code>
public static void main (String args[]){
System.out.println('Hello World!\\n');
return 0;}
</code>

The last line ....
"""

def matches = ctext =~ /(?s)<code>(.*?)<\/code>/
matches.each { println it[1] }
```

produces:

```
int main(){
printf('Hello World!\n');
return 0;}


public static void main (String args[]){
System.out.println('Hello World!\n');
return 0;}
```

As can be tested on: http://ideone.com/JQ0Ck

Comment: I tried this on the groovy console, but getting the following output: `java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=(?s)<code>(.*?)</code> region=0,306 lastmatch=]`. Seems like no match, coz I think, 0th element of matcher contains whole string ..

Comment: try `matches.each { println it[1] }`

Comment: @tim_yates `matches.each { println it[1] }` this code is working well, Just one last query to both of you: What is the difference between `println matches[0][0]; println matches[1][0]` AND `matches.each { println it[1] }`, coz with the first one, I am getting the `<code>` tag and with the second one without `<code>` as i want. and at last many thanks to both of u.

Comment: @Zedwal, `matches[1][0]` returns the match at index 1 (so, that's the second match) and from that match it returns group 0 (which is the entire match, including `<code>` tags). If you'd do  `matches[0][1]` and `matches[1][1]` you'll see the same as if you'd do `.each{ ... it[1] }`

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Have you tried the `(?m)` modifier for multi line regular expressions?</strike>

Bart Kiers mentioned in his comment that this is not useful, you have to use the dot-all modifier `(?s)`. Thank you for pointing this out Bart.

Comment: No, `(?m)` makes `^` match line starts instead of just the start-of-input and `$` match line endings instead of just the end-of-input.